# Invalid Identifier in Temp Table Left Join Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, temp-tables

Good Evening EST,

I am stuck on the below query, I keep getting an invalid identifier error at line 12, the first "DELETE FLAG". Not sure if I'm missing some syntax or doing something else silly. (I have very thoroughly checked I didn't misspell anything and all the fields exist)

Oracle SQL Developer V. 17.2 Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
      CM.SUBJECT_PERSON_ID,
      CM.COHORT_SCOPED_IDENTIFIER AS SUBJECT_STUDY_ID,
      SA3.ALT_ID_VALUE AS GLOBAL_SUBJECT_ID,
      V.PREFERRED_TERM AS MEMBER_STATUS,
      CM.COHORT_ID,
      SA2.ALT_ID_VALUE AS CRIN_ID
 FROM GLENAPO.COHORT_MEMBER CM
                LEFT JOIN GLENAPO.SUBJECT_ALT_ID SA1
         ON     SA2.SUBJECT_PERSON_ID =CM.SUBJECT_PERSON_ID
            AND SA2.IDENTIFIER_TYPE_ID = 8 -- get SDG_ID
            AND SA2.DELETE_FLAG = 'N'
           LEFT JOIN GLENAPO.SUBJECT_ALT_ID SA1
         ON     SA2.SUBJECT_PERSON_ID =CM.SUBJECT_PERSON_ID
            AND SA2.IDENTIFIER_TYPE_ID = 8 -- get SDG_ID
            AND SA2.DELETE_FLAG = 'N'
      LEFT JOIN GLENAPO.SUBJECT_ALT_ID SA2
         ON     SA2.SUBJECT_PERSON_ID =CM.SUBJECT_PERSON_ID
            AND SA2.IDENTIFIER_TYPE_ID = 18 -- get CRIN ID
            AND SA2.DELETE_FLAG = 'N'
      JOIN GLENAPO.SUBJECT_ALT_ID SA3
         ON     SA3.SUBJECT_PERSON_ID =CM.SUBJECT_PERSON_ID
            AND SA3.IDENTIFIER_TYPE_ID = 12 -- get Global Subject
            AND SA3.DELETE_FLAG = 'N'
      LEFT JOIN GLENAPO.VOCAB_TERM_VIEW V
         ON     V.TABLE_NAME = 'COHORT_MEMBER'
            AND V.COLUMN_NAME = 'STATUS_CODE'
            AND V.CONCEPT_ID = CM.STATUS_CODE
      LEFT JOIN GLENAPO.FACILITY_REFERENCE FR ON FR.FACILITY_ID = CM.FACILITY_ID      
WHERE CM.DELETE_FLAG = 'N'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the beginning of your `FROM` clause:

```
 FROM GLENAPO.COHORT_MEMBER CM LEFT JOIN
      GLENAPO.SUBJECT_ALT_ID SA1
      ON SA2.SUBJECT_PERSON_ID = CM.SUBJECT_PERSON_ID AND
         SA2.IDENTIFIER_TYPE_ID = 8 AND -- get SDG_ID
         SA2.DELETE_FLAG = 'N'
```

A table alias needs to be defined before it is used.  I think you intend `SA1`, rather than `SA2`:

```
 FROM GLENAPO.COHORT_MEMBER CM LEFT JOIN
      GLENAPO.SUBJECT_ALT_ID SA1
      ON SA1.SUBJECT_PERSON_ID = CM.SUBJECT_PERSON_ID AND
         SA1.IDENTIFIER_TYPE_ID = 8 AND -- get SDG_ID
         SA1.DELETE_FLAG = 'N'
```